# How do I customize Quick Website Search keywords in Mobile Safari?

Tags: mobile-safari, search-engine

Is it possible to customize the keyword for a Quick Website Search in Mobile Safari?

I'm willing to do some direct editing in preferences files if that's what it takes.

**Background:**

I'm using an iPad 3, one of the models that is limited to iOS 9.3.5, and I recently discovered that this version supports Quick Website Search, which is analogous to the Quick Searches and Manage Search Engines features in Firefox and Chrome respectively that I use all the time on the desktop.  However in both of these browsers it is possible to customize the keyword that is used for a given search.

In fact I already I do some analogous file meddling with Chrome by loading my quick searches directly into its SQLite-based configuration file with a small script, to avoid the rigmarole of having to visit each site and then edit its keyword through the not great settings UI for it.